# How to obtain the posterior density, $p(\theta | \alpha, \beta, y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

**Text:** Bayesian Data Analysis 3E by Gelman

**Section:** 5.3 Bayesian analysis of conjugate hierarchical models

**Pages:** 109-110

I am trying to follow an example about rat tumor experiments.

Let $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_J)$ and $\theta = (\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_J)$ be such that 
$$y_j \overset{\text{ind}}{\sim} \mathrm{Bin}(n_j, \theta_j),$$
where $n_j$ is known for all $j = 1,2,\ldots, J,$

$$\theta_j \overset{\text{ind}}{\sim} \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha, \beta),$$
and $$(\alpha, \beta) \sim \text{noninformative hyperprior}$$

The text says the following:

> Given $(\alpha, \beta)$, the components of $\theta$ have independent posterior densities that are of the form $\theta_j ^A (1 - \theta_j)^B$ -- that is, beta densities -- and the joint density is 
>   $$p(\theta | \alpha, \beta, y) = \prod\limits_{j = 1}^J \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + n_j)}{\Gamma(\alpha + y_j) \Gamma(\beta + n_j - y_j)} \theta_j^{\alpha + y_j -1} (1 - \theta_j)^{\beta + n_j - y_j - 1}$$
>   How is the equality obtained?

---

**My work:**

I know that 
$$\begin{align}
p(\theta | \alpha, \beta, y) &\propto p(\theta | \alpha, \beta) p(y | \theta, \alpha, \beta) \\
&\propto \prod \limits_{j = 1}^J \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \theta_j^{\alpha - 1} (1 - \theta_j)^{\beta - 1} 
\prod \limits_{j = 1}^J \theta_j^{y_j} (1 - \theta)^{n_j - y_j} \\
&= \prod \limits_{j = 1}^J \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \theta_j^{\alpha + y_j - 1} (1 - \theta_j)^{\beta +n_j - y_j - 1} 
\end{align}$$

I almost have the product of independent $\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha + y_j, \beta + n_j - y_j)$ random variables. Now I find the proper normalizing "constant".

$$\begin{align}
&...  \prod \limits_{j = 1}^J \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \theta_j^{\alpha + y_j - 1} (1 - \theta_j)^{\beta +n_j - y_j - 1} \\
&= \prod \limits_{j=1}^J \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + y_j) \Gamma(\beta + n_j - y_j)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + n_j)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + n_j)}{\Gamma(\alpha + y_j) \Gamma(\beta + n_j - y_j)} \theta_j^{\alpha + y_j - 1} (1 - \theta_j)^{\beta +n_j - y_j - 1} \\
&= \prod \limits_{j=1}^J \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + y_j) \Gamma(\beta + n_j - y_j)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + n_j)} 
\prod \limits_{j=1}^J \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + n_j)}{\Gamma(\alpha + y_j) \Gamma(\beta + n_j - y_j)} \theta_j^{\alpha + y_j - 1} (1 - \theta_j)^{\beta +n_j - y_j - 1}
\end{align}$$

So now I need to show that $\prod \limits_{j=1}^J \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + y_j) \Gamma(\beta + n_j - y_j)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + n_j)} = 1$, but I don't believe this is true. Actually, I've tried a few cases where I fix $J = 1$ and use some easy values for $\alpha, \beta, y_j, n_j$ and I don't get that it equals one.

Can someone offer another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are there as soon as you have
$$
p(\theta|\alpha,\beta,y)\propto\prod_{j=1}^{J}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\theta_j^{\alpha+y_j-1}(1-\theta_j)^{\beta+n_j-y_j-1},
$$
in fact can just throw away the constant that seems to be confusing matters and write
$$
p(\theta|\alpha,\beta,y)\propto\prod_{j=1}^{J}\theta_j^{\alpha+y_j-1}(1-\theta_j)^{\beta+n_j-y_j-1},
$$
to find the normalising constant you have
$$
\begin{align}
\int\cdots\int\prod_{j=1}^J\theta_j^{\alpha+y_j-1}(1-\theta_j)^{\beta+n_j-y_j-1}\operatorname{d}\theta_1\cdots\operatorname{d}\theta_J&=\prod_{j=1}^{J}\int\theta_j^{\alpha+y_j-1}(1-\theta_j)^{\beta+n_j-y_j-1}\operatorname{d}\theta_j \\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{J} B(\alpha+y_j, \beta +n_j-y_j)
\end{align}
$$
and then just put it all together
$$
\begin{align}
p(\theta|\alpha,\beta,y)&=\frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^{J}B(\alpha+y_j, \beta + n_j - y_j)}\theta_j^{\alpha+y_j-1}(1-\theta_j)^{\beta+n_j-y_j-1} \\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{J}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+n_j)}{\Gamma(\alpha+y_j)\Gamma(\beta + n_j - y_j)}\theta_j^{\alpha+y_j-1}(1-\theta_j)^{\beta+n_j-y_j-1}.
\end{align}
$$